# how can I use data from the frontend to make a http request on my server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, httprequest

I have a http request in node:

```
    var options = {
    method: 'POST'
    , url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?'
    , qs: 
   { location: '44.019076299999995, -123.10060789999999',
     type: 'restaurant',
     opennow: 'true',
     rankby: 'distance',
     key: 'my key' }
    , headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        , 'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    , json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {data : body.results});
    });
});
```

But I am stuck on how I can can get data from the user on the front end to use in my request. for example I am getting the users coordinates using geolocation on the front end. how can I plug this into my request? what about if the user wanted to add a search parameter? I know I can have my user make the request on the front end with ajax, but that leaves me with the problem of having my api key exposed on the front end. What is the pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but if you want to get informations from your client, why don't you create a POST route and send the informations you need to your API, then you can insert it into your request

Comment: @boehm_s So I can create a POST request from my front end then make a second post from my server?

Comment: You can make your users send you the informations you need through a POST request to your API, then, when you recieve the informations you need, you can put them into the request you do from your server.